# keep the name of the input vector's element in the output of the function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, vector

I have two functions `f1` and `f2`. In its output, `f1` always keeps the name of the element of the inputted vector `x`.

But in its output, `f2` always deletes the name of the element of the inputted vector `x`.

Is there a way for `f2` to keep the name of the element in its output just like `f1`?

```
x <- 1:10
x <- setNames(x, letters[1:10])

f1 <- function(x, n){
  
  sort(x)[n]
} 
# EXAMPLE OF USE:
f1(x, 2)

# OUTPUT:
# b       # Notice "b"
# 2

f2 <- function(x, n){
  
  len <- length(x)
  sort(x, partial = len-n+1)[len-n+1]
}

# EXAMPLE OF USE:
f2(x, 2)

# OUTPUT:
# [1] 9     # Notice no name is attached to 9.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `sort` function, it says that if `partial` is not `null`, names are discarded. See [sort](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/sort) function documentation.
In `f2`, `sort(x, partial = len-n+1)[len-n+1]`, just little more messy,

```
f2 <- function(x, n){
  
  len <- length(x)
  x[x == sort(x, partial = len-n+1)[len-n+1]]
}
f2(x, 2)

i 
9
```

but this will keep name of value.